# Linq to XML - how to get the value of a attribute

Tags: linq-to-xml

`

```
XElement config = XElement.Parse (
@"<Response SessionId='426D9AEB1F684849A16D79A6CF48582B' xmlns='http://schemas.tmaresources.com/timssws60.xsd'>
<Status Success='true' Message='Connected' ErrorCode='0' />
</Response>");

XElement response = config.Element("Response");

sessionID = (string)response.Attribute("SessionId");`
```

why is response null in this case? how can I get the attribute value SessionId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `config` variable contains the `<Response>` element itself.
Calling `config.Element("Response")` will try to get a `<Response>` element *inside* the `<Response>` element.
Since there isn't any, it returns `null`.

Change it to

```
(string)config.Attribute("SessionId")
```